# Crafting Business logic in Axon framework

Tags: spring-boot, domain-driven-design, cqrs, axon

Being a newbie I'm slowly adapting to Axon Framework. I'm creating 2 aggregate classes bicycle aggregate and Slots aggregate, my usecase is bicycle has to be parked. parkBicycle command has inputs bicycle id and slot id I need to check States of both bicycle and slot before successfully executing parkBicycle command how do I do it

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will want to use a saga - you will first need to check that the slot is existing and available, lock it so that another command does not park another bike in the meantime, then attempt to change the state of the bike (if existing). If the bike does not exist or is already parked somewhere else, you unlock the parking slot.